# Error adding GeoServer store from PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, ubuntu

I can't get a connection up when creating a PostGIS-store.

- GeoServer is running fine on IP:80/GeoServer.
- PostGIS is running and working fine with PSQL commands
- Created database/table 'mydb' and 'mytable' then changed ownership to Postgres

ERROR MESSAGE

```
Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "postgres", database "main", SSL off)
```

PG_HBA.CONF 
    # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
    #local   all             postgres                                peer
    local   all             postgres                                trust
    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             128.187.0.0/16          md5
host    all             all             69.169.0.0/16           md5
#allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

I'm on a Ubuntu on AWS-EC2.

Comment: What happens when you add `local   all  postgres  md5`?

Comment: I have a geoserver and several datastore postgis (ownership: postgres) on my machine. The only different with your pg_hba.conf file is the METHOD: trust; however I have enabled also LISTEN ADDRESS: "*" in postgresql.conf

Comment: What is the security group configuration on your EC2 instance? I resolved this error connecting to my RDS instance by opening the right port in the EC2 security group. Given postgres is running on the same instance, the security group might/not apply.